# Complex numbers inequality $|a_nb_n+...+a_mb_m|≤a_n * \max_{n≤k≤m} |b_n+b_{n+1}+...b_k|$

Tags: geometry, inequality, complex-numbers

$a_n,...,a_m \in R $, such that $a_n≥a_{n+1}≥...≥a_m≥0$
and any $b_n,...,b_m \in C$
How to conclude $$|a_nb_n+...+a_mb_m|≤a_n * \max_{n≤k≤m} |b_n+b_{n+1}+...b_k|$$
It is said in the book, that if the complex numbers $b$ will be represented as vectors. Then $max$ will mean smallest possible circle radius to keep the broken line made of $b$ vectors inside.
(to the end of $b_n$ we attach the beginning of $b_{n+1}$ and so on).
  I understand it, but don't comprehend why the whole statement is right.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=0$, the statement is vacuously true. So let $a_n>0$. Let $c_k:=a_k/a_n$, so that $1=c_n\ge c_{n-1}\ge \cdots\ge c_{m}\ge 0$. Now, use induction on $m$:

If $m=n$, we have $$|\sum_{k=n}^m c_k b_k|=|b_n|\le\max_{n\le k\le n}|b_n+\cdots+b_k|$$ Let it be true for $m>p>n$. Then, $|\sum_{k=n}^p c_k b_k|\le \max_{n\le k\le p}|b_n+\cdots+b_k|$. Then, $$|\sum_{k=n}^{p+1}c_kb_k|=|\sum_{k=n}^{p-1}c_kb_k+c_{p}b_p+c_{p+1}b_{p+1}|$$ If $c_p=0$, the induction hypothesis implies that$$|\sum_{k=n}^{p+1}c_kb_k|=|\sum_{k=n}^{p-1}c_kb_k|\le \max_{n\le k\le p+1}|b_1+\cdots+b_{k}|$$ So , let $c_p>0$. Then, note that $c_pb_p+c_{p+1}b_{p+1}=c_{p}b_{p}'$, where, $b_p'=b_p+db_{p+1}$, where $d=c_{p+1}/c_p\le 1$, then by induction hypothesis, $|b_p'|\le \max_{p\le k\le p+1}|b_p+b_k|$.

Finally, using induction hypothesis once more, $$|\sum_{k=n}^{p+1}c_kb_k|=|\sum_{k=n}^{p-1}c_kb_k+c_{p}b_p'|\le \max\{|b_n+\cdots+b_{k}|,|b_n+\cdots+b_p'|:n\le k\le p-1\}\le \max\{|b_n+\cdots+b_{k}|:n\le k\le p+1\} $$